# How to solve the integral $\int \sqrt {\sin x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How to solve the integral $ \int{\sqrt{\sin x+1} }\hspace{.1cm} dx$ with steps.

Comment: I edited your title to bring it into conformity with the body of your question.  You had originally written $\int \sin x + 1$ in the title . . .

Comment: Kinda pissed off I spent 10 minutes writing two different solutions to not be able to post it.

Comment: @DavidPeterson That is why, as a rule of thumb, I avoid answering questions as low quality as this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $1+\cos{x}=2\cos^2\frac{x}{2}$ and $\sin{x}=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$.